# iOS - CAEmitterCell using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, particle-system, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I'm trying to create a particle system for an iOS app. the app doesn't use SpriteKit, so i'm using CAEmitterLayer and CAEmitterCell to do it. In Objective - C, i initialized a CAEmitterCell this way:

```
[CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
```

but in swift there isn't such initializer. Looking at Swift documentation, there's no method to create and initialize a CAEmmiterCell.

Is there any way of implementing a particle system using CAEmitterCell in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how that initialization is done in Swift:

```
 CAEmitterCell()
```

If you want to assign it to a variable:

```
 var emitterCell = CAEmitterCell()
```

You'll definitely want to read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_25) about how to initialize Objective-C objects with Swift.